# Predicted class probabilities for both classes in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, probability

I have a binary classification problem and I would like to get the predicted class probabilities for both the classes. Something like this...

```
0 0.25 0.15
0  0.2 0.19
1 0.19 0.25
```

Each line contains the item's actual class, the predicted probability for membership of class-0, and the predicted probability for membership of class-1.I could get the predicted probability for class-1 using the predict function

`predict(mod,newx=ValidX,type="response")`

Please advice on how to get the probabilities for class-0.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Subtract from 1 the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a binary classification, the Prob(C2) = 1 - Prob(C1)

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with R, but this seems more like a general machine learning question to me. With regards to your problem (i.e binary classification with a single output), the [answer provided by tyumru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50426827/2113717) is probably the one you should consider.

That being said, some machine learning algorithms will output the probability for each class out of the box. For instance, if you use a neural network with the softmax activation function on the output layer, you will get a probability per class.